# Using an existing slide to create master slide views

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Is there a way I could transfer normal slides in powerpoint to master view? As in, I want ALL my slides from a presentation to be slide views.

Explanation: the request was to just make a presentation about how the company presentations should look like, but after seeing it, they would like to make all of the slides avaliable as templates(views, some of them with predifined text and images), and the design of presentation an actual theme.

Is there a simple way of doing it or do I have to manually make the Master & Slide views? Based on my research, the answer is NO, but I would like to confirm that before I waste hours to copy and make the whole master.

Any information or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is done as follows :

- In the normal slide, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all
  the items on the slide and copy them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- Go into Master View and paste the items onto a new Master Slide.
- Convert the text into placeholder text where you want it to be editable
  in Normal View.

Comment: Thanks, that will at least shorten the proces for some time. Was hoping there was a better way, but it'll have to do :)

EDIT: It actually doesn't work, when I try to paste nothing happens... Any idea how to solve it? @harrymc

Comment: I cant edit the comment again, sorry for duoble posting. That approach works only for single slides, so I will assume theres no faster way to do it for all the slides. Still thanks for the anwer.

Comment: This is a nice trick! I was checking other ways but this seems to be the only one that works.

Comment: This doesn't copy slide backgrounds.

Comment: This breaks down at the 3rd step. "Convert the text into placeholder text" as AFAIK, there is no way to actually do this, except to create new placeholders and copy/paste text from the text boxes to placeholders, which can be a considerable amount of work to duplicate the size, position, font styles, etc. to be exactly the same as you want it. So this isn't really very useful.